# Potential outcome: am I interpreting it right?

Tags: econometrics, interpretation

I have followed a course of applied microeconomics and a chapter was based on microeconometrics. Unfortunately I did not understand the introductory part very well, so now I'm a bit concerned that what I know is not completely right. I hope you can confirm if I'm wrong or right.

Suppose we have a dummy variable $D \in \left \{ 0,1 \right \}$, telling us whether a patient undergoes a medical treatment or not. Let $Y_i$ be the observation for the i-esim patient, then we have the following potential outcome for $Y$:

$$Y_i = \left\{\begin{matrix}
 Y_{1i} \quad if \ D_i=1
\\Y_{0i} \quad if \ D_i=0
\end{matrix}\right.$$

From this I can now write that:

$$Y_i=Y_{0i} + (Y_{1i}-Y_{0i})D_i$$

Is it right to read/interpret the last equation as follow? *The observation of patient $i$ is given by the observation of his medical status before the treatment* ($Y_{0i}$) *plus the causal effect* ($Y_{1i}-Y_{0i}$) *knowing that* $D_i=1$. *The causal effect is the observation of his medical status after the treatment* ($Y_{1i}$) *minus the counterfactual, which is what his medical status would have been if patient $i$ did not undergo the treatment (unobservable for the i-esim patient).*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first equation says your actual outcome, $Y_i$, equals the potential outcome, $Y_{0i}$ or $Y_{1i}$, that matches what actually happened ($D_i$).

The second equation is actually identical to the first, the formula just looks different. It says your outcome is the non-treated outcome, unless you were treated, in which case you add the difference between the treated and non-treated responses, which results in the treated outcome.

The patient's medical status before treatment is not involved in these equations, so your interpretation is not quite the same as the original. However, if the pre- and post-study $Y$ values are the same for non-treated subjects, your interpretation would be right.